# Retornar uma consulta PDO em um array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Como faço para realizar uma consulta com `PDO` e retornar os resultados em um `array`.

Ex: Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorne 10 linhas, cada linha tem 3 colunas

```
<?php

$equipe1 = $_POST['equipe1'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$equipe2 = $_POST ['equipe2'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];//Define a dificuldade das perguntas      que seram selecionadas
$rodada = $_POST ['rodada'];//Número de perguntas que serão retornadas

echo $equipe1;
echo $equipe2;

switch ($dificuldade) {
  case '1':
   $dificuldade = "Facil";
  break;

  case '2':
   $dificuldade = "Medio";
  break;

  case '3':
   $dificuldade = "Dificil";
  break;
}

switch ($rodada) {
  case '1':
    $rodada = "10";
  break;
  case '2':
    $rodada = "15";
  break;
  case '3':
    $rodada = "20";
  break;

try{
 $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=teocratico; charset=utf8","root","");
 } catch (PDOException $erro){
   echo $erro->getmessage();
   //header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
 }


$consulta = $conexao -> query ("SELECT id_pergunta, pergunta, resposta, desafio FROM perguntas 
where dificuldade ='$dificuldade' LIMIT $rodada ORDER BY RAND()

");
// Vamos imprimir os nossos resultados
  while($row = $consulta->fetch()) {
      echo $row['id_pergunta']. ' - '. $row['pergunta'] . ' - ' .    $row['resposta'] . ''. $row ['desafio'];
  }
}


?>
```

Comment: nao entendi muito bem o que quer.. O que quer de diferente do que esta agora?

Comment: Qual é o problema com o código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei bem se é duplicada...

Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
// Cria conexão com o banco de dados
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".dbhost.";dbname=".dbschema.";charset=utf8;", dbuser, dbpassword);
// Seta atributos para gerar erros caso ocorra alguma exceção
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// Faz a consulta
$sql = "Sua consulta SQL";
$query = $db->query($sql);
// O segredo esta nesta linha abaixo \/
$return = $query->fetch();
```

Existem 4 diretivas do `fetch` que pessoalmente eu acho interessantes para se usar em uma consulta:

`$query->fetch();` // Te retorna somente um elemento da consulta, creio que o primeiro... Se a consulta possuir mais de um elemento, os outros são ignorados

`$query->fetchAll();` // Te retorna todos os elementos da consulta

E ainda pode passar como parâmetro:

`$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` // Te retorna um elemento do tipo `array`, que pode ser acessado assim: $query["elemento"]

`$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` // Te retorna um elemento do tipo `object`, que pode ser acessado assim: $query->elemento

Existem ainda muito outras diretivas que podem ser acessadas [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

---

Desse modo se você possuir por exemplo a seguinte tabela:

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Nome        |   Email                   |   Sexo    |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Joaozinho   |   joao@joao.joao          |   H       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Mariazinha  |   maria@maria.maria       |   M       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Carlinhos   |   carlos@carlos.carlos    |   H       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Para atingir o objetivo de exibir todos os elementos você poderia fazer:

```
$return = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($return as &$value) {
    echo "Nome: ".$value['nome']." Email: ".$value['email']." Sexo: ".$value['sexo'];
}
```

Comment: A query não executa, testei direto no banco e funcionou.

Comment: while($row = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['id_pergunta']. ' - '. $row['pergunta'] . ' - ' . $row['resposta'] . ''. $row ['desafio'];
  }

Comment: Mas quando faço no PHP não funciona. ele da Undefined index:  no array.

Comment: Note que o modo que esta executando esta diferente da minha resposta rs em qual array ele da undefined index?